# In bash, grep for a line beginning with \, and assign the result using backticks

Tags: bash, shell, grep, quoting, command-substitution

In bash, I'm trying to grep a file for a line beginning with a \, and return the result using backticks.

For example:

```
echo \\Hello > myFile
out=`cat myFile | grep '^\\Hello'`
echo $out
```

returns nothing, even though

```
cat myFile | grep '^\\Hello'
```

returns, as epected.

```
\Hello
```

This seems extremely odd shell behavior.    In particular, the anologous command sequence in tcsh does what one would expect:

```
set out=`cat myFile | grep '^\\Hello'`; echo $out
```

returns

```
\Hello
```

Could somebody explain what's going on please?    Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 and especially

> Backslashes inside backticks are handled in a non-obvious manner

:

```
`...`
```

is the legacy syntax required by only the very oldest of non-POSIX-compatible bourne-shells. There are several reasons to always prefer the `$(...)` syntax, so :

```
echo \\Hello > myFile
```

and instead of

```
out=$(cat myFile | grep '^\\Hello')
```

simplify it a bit :

```
out=$(grep '^\\Hello' myFile)
```

then

```
echo $out
```

And  "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: "$var", "$(command "$var")", "${array[@]}", "a & b". Use 'single quotes' for code or literal $'s: 'Costs $5 US', ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words .

So finally :

```
echo \\Hello > myFile
out="$(grep '^\\Hello' myFile)"
echo "$out"
```